# Why CAN this TryGetValue/TryUpdate on ConcurrentDictionary get deadlocked?

Tags: c#, concurrency, deadlock, concurrentdictionary

I am getting a deadlock when I run IncrementModelClientReOrderCount but the problem goes away when I run IncrementModelClientReOrderCountLOCK.

The difference is a lock() statement.

I has assumed that the use of a ConcurrentDictionary had mitigated against the chance of a deadlock.

Am I using the ConcurrentDictionary incorrectly perhaps:

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<Connection, ModelClient> ModelClients = new ConcurrentDictionary<Connection, ModelClient>();



    public bool IncrementModelClientReOrderCount(Connection mc)
    {
            ModelClient curValue;
            while (ModelClients.TryGetValue(mc, out curValue))
            {
                ModelClient curValue2 = curValue.Clone() as ModelClient; 
                curValue2.reOrderCount++;
                curValue2.DSP.seen = false;
                if (ModelClients.TryUpdate(mc, curValue2, curValue))
                    return true;

            }
            return false; 
    }


    public bool IncrementModelClientReOrderCountLOCK(Connection mc)
    {
        lock (ModelClients)
        {

            ModelClient curValue;
            while (ModelClients.TryGetValue(mc, out curValue))
            {
                ModelClient curValue2 = curValue.Clone() as ModelClient; 
                curValue2.reOrderCount++;
                curValue2.DSP.seen = false;
                if (ModelClients.TryUpdate(mc, curValue2, curValue))
                    return true;
            }
            return false; 
        }

    }


public class ModelClient : ICloneable
    {
        public string Symbol;
        public int Amount;
        public double Price;

        public ModelClient(string Symbol, int Amount, double Price)
        {
            this.Symbol = Symbol;
            this.Amount = Amount;
            this.Price = Price;
        }

        public object Clone() { return this.MemberwiseClone(); }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you assume that the deadlock is caused by the `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov OK. I grant it might be something else, but it does occur in the method. Do you see something else that might be the culprit?

Comment: Is `Clone` a custom implementation?

Comment: No, see edit : I appended class for ModelClient

Comment: This question is obviously in *great* need of a stack trace of the deadlocked threads.

Comment: Yes agreed. I will try an recreate issue, but I have not got an example handy. What about the basic way I using TryGetValue/TryUpdate - does that look correct to you?

Comment: CD never deadlocks if all you do is call methods on it. That's because CD never calls user code under a lock. Something else is going on not visible here.

Comment: @usr but CD *does* use `lock` and user code is free to call two CD methods that lock the same data from different threads (i.e. the condition for a deadlock).  Plus, you can config the concurrency multiplier increasing the probability of blocking. I don't think that's going on here; but not enough info.

Comment: @PeterRitchie CD can block but never deadlock.

Comment: You and I clearly have a different definition of deadlock if you think anything that blocks doesn't have the capability to deadlock.

Comment: Can you please provide stack trace? It really seems to be not a problem of ConcurrentDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

A "thread-safe" collection is thread-safe unto itself--not to all other code that didn't exist when the collection was written.  `ConncurrentDictionary` is also not lock-free--which means it *does* lock and thus has a potential to block on calls to some of its methods. (e.g. two threads dependent on one another for forward progress both calling a blocking method on `ConcurrentDictionary` at the same time)

The nature of a lock is such that it guards two pieces of code from executing at the same time and potentially corrupting state--which means there's almost always more than one place in the code that uses `lock` and thus you can write code that overlaps execution of those two blocks and causes a deadlock.

A thread-safe collection means only that you can use it from multiple threads and it itself will not corrupt its own state (a state you don't have access to and cannot protect yourself).  Use of a thread-safe collection doesn't automatically make all of your code thread-safe nor does it free you from having to understand areas of potential deadlock and compensate for them with your own thread-safety primitives.

You haven't provided enough code for anyone to tell exactly how you're getting into a deadlock (or whether it is in fact a livelock).  But, `TryUpdate` can block *and* if another thread called `TryUpdate` with the same `curValue`, I would expect `TryUpdate` would return false and your code would try all over again (i.e. potential live lock

It appears you have an invariant between when you get the value via `TryGetValue` and when you update it with `TryUpdate`.  This invariant is unique to your code and you need to guard it.  `lock` is a good start; but you likely need to understand it better before you accept that `lock` is the best solution.